# What extra documents can I include in Italy visa request?

Tags: visas, paperwork, italy

I am preparing my visa request and I've included all the required documents. My friends advised me to add extra documents to convince the Embassy. Is it really helpful to include my visa card copy or my car ownership card? What extra documents can can include?

Comment: Yes, add any additional proofs of the legitimacy of your trip as you have.

Answer (score 1):

Your supporting documents, in addition to your transportation arrangements (such as round trip airline tickets), would be bank statements or official affidavits of support, a letter in which you explain the purpose of your travels, a reference letter from your employer that includes permission to be absent. As evidence of your ability to underwrite your travels, you could include credit card information that shows your credit limits. For ties to your home country, showing property ownership can be helpful, but that is generally understood to be real estate. The local consular services of the EU country to which you are applying will have the precise requirements and supporting documents you are expected to provide.